# Emacs python development - integration shell with char mode

Tags: python, linux, shell, emacs

I'm developing Python and find `C-c C-c` (python-shell-send-buffer) and related features of Python mode very usefull. 
At the same time i prefer `term` in char sub-mode over `Inferior Python`, to get familiar access to kill-ring and autocomplete.

Is there a *simple* way to make Python mode use `term` rather than `Inferior Python`?

I've tried various instructions for basic settings that should do this but they fail for me, so I try to present the core question here. 
I would prefer a *simple* solution, ideally configuration/installation of mode(s) only, and no custom lisp, as I'm still trying to grasp the basic of emacs customisation (And, admited!, lazy).

Python mode: I simply use the one shipped with Linux Mint 17, emacs 24 (Please provide instructions if you want to know version e.g.).

Thanks!

Comment: My suggestion is to use eclipse+pydev or pycharm. Both are far superior to emacs for python development. If you were a hardcore emacs nut I'd say maybe thats a good idea, but if you're new to emacs don't even start...

Comment: [Religion comming up :)] I've used Eclipse some for java, and I'm not really a fan of the way the editor works, on the other hand I love(yup!) editing text in emacs, so that is not really a solution. But thank you for the suggestion!